# Pareto package in R

Tags: r, statistics

How I get the qpareto function in R? When I type `qpareto(.05/2, 2, 15)`, R doesn't recognize what the `qpareto` function is. I tried typing `library(VGAM)` and that didn't pop anything up either. Neither did `library(rmutils)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the packages first:

```
install.packages(c("VGAM","rmutils"))
```